# Show the data based on Hierarchy [ Grand Parent -> Parent -> Child ]

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hi I want to show data as Hierarchy way like this as show in below image

[image]

and here is my database table structure

[image]

and here is the query i have used but its not the perfect result i want

```
SELECT 

t1.parent_id AS primary_Id,
t2.parent_id AS secondary_Id,
t3.parent_id AS teritiary_Id

FROM ucode AS t1
LEFT JOIN ucode AS t2 ON t2.parent_id = t1.id
LEFT JOIN ucode AS t3 ON t3.parent_id = t2.parent_id
```

and the output is

[image]

this is not i need

and one more way i tried

```
SELECT 
    
    t1.parent_id AS primary_Id,
    t2.parent_id AS secondary_Id,
    t3.parent_id AS teritiary_Id
    
    FROM ucode AS t1
    LEFT JOIN ucode AS t2 ON t2.parent_id = t1.id
    LEFT JOIN ucode AS t3 ON t3.parent_id = t2.id
```

and the output is

[image]

### can you give me the proper solution for this..

Comment: Change the last line to `LEFT JOIN ucode AS t3 ON t3.parent_id = t2.id`

Comment: No Even The result is wrong you can check the result in the question..! i added that result

Comment: So you want to show tree view structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the query

```
Select gparent, parent, id from ucode as c_tbl,
(SELECT gparent, id as parent from ucode as p_tbl,
(SELECT id as gparent FROM `ucode` WHERE parent_id = 0) as gp_tbl
where p_tbl.parent_id = gp_tbl.gparent) parent_tbl
where c_tbl.parent_id = parent_tbl.parent;
```

Click [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ca0fb/3) for the result

Comment: But writing SQL query in sub quires is **very bad** we have to write in joins

Answer (score 0):

You need to Use `INNER JOIN` instead LEFT JOIN and to limit query to return only parents with child use `WHERE`

My query doesn't skip the column value as you wanted to show but you can do it PHP while looping the below query result.

```
SELECT 
    t1.parent_id AS primary_Id,
    t2.parent_id AS secondary_Id,
    t3.parent_id AS teritiary_Id
FROM ucode AS t1
INNER JOIN ucode AS t2 ON (t2.parent_id = t1.id )
INNER JOIN ucode AS t3 ON (t3.parent_id = t2.id )
where t1.parent_id = 0
```

**[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ca0fb/1)**

Comment: Thank you for the Response actually..! your result is good not exact answer as per your output secondary_id result should come in primary_id and teritiary_Id result should come in secondary_id and teritiary_Id  should be 
3 , 4, 6, 7 , 10, 11, 13, 14

Comment: But this is not your expected, `I want to show data as Hierarchy way like this as show in below image` ?